# exec-maven-plugin when invoked breaks the default maven lifecycle

Tags: java, maven

I have been using exec-maven-plugin for quite some time now, but this problem seems to be too complex for me to understand. My project is multi module project and as soon as the following plugin is invoked it does the work it is expected to do but maven seem to just break out of the default lifecycle. Looks like some problem with my mainClass but not sure what.

POM.xml snippet follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>genclient.proxies.platform</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mschematic.tools.proxygen.WsProxyGen</mainClass>
                        <cleanupDaemonThreads>true</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                        <daemonThreadJoinTimeout>15000</daemonThreadJoinTimeout>
                        <stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads>true</stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-p</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.client.platform</argument>
                            <argument>-d</argument>
                            <argument>${project.basedir}/generated-sources/platform-beans</argument>
                            <argument>-wc</argument>
                            <argument>cu-platform-wsv-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</argument>
                            <argument>-wbn</argument>
                            <argument>WebBean</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.AlertService</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.ApplConfig</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.AuditService</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.AuthorityManager</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.BookingManager</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.CaseManager</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.CustomDataService</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.CustomerHistory</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.DocumentManager</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.FinancialTool</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.FormsManager</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.IdentityService</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.Inbox</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.Monitoring</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.ProcessDirectory</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.ProductManager</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.Reference</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.Sales</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.Scripting</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.ServicingService</argument>
                            <argument>com.mschematic.platform.services.WaitList</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </build>
```

The debug logs snippet follows:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) mainClass = com.mschematic.tools.proxygen.WsProxyGen
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDependencies = [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.4.0:, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.mschematic.base.services.ifxclient:cu-services-ifx-client:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ F:\khaja\cu-maven\channelUnited\parent\base\cu-services\cu-services-ifx-client\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [       id: central
      url: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stopUnresponsiveDaemonThreads = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Invoking : com.mschematic.tools.proxygen.WsProxyGen.main(-p, com.mschematic.client.platform, -d, F:\khaja\cu-maven\channelUnited\parent\base\cu-services\cu-services-ifx-client/generated-sources/platform-beans, -wc, cu-platform-wsv-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, -wbn, WebBean, com.mschematic.platform.services.AlertService, com.mschematic.platform.services.ApplConfig, com.mschematic.platform.services.AuditService, com.mschematic.platform.services.AuthorityManager, com.mschematic.platform.services.BookingManager, com.mschematic.platform.services.CaseManager, com.mschematic.platform.services.CustomDataService, com.mschematic.platform.services.CustomerHistory, com.mschematic.platform.services.DocumentManager, com.mschematic.platform.services.FinancialTool, com.mschematic.platform.services.FormsManager, com.mschematic.platform.services.IdentityService, com.mschematic.platform.services.Inbox, com.mschematic.platform.services.Monitoring, com.mschematic.platform.services.ProcessDirectory, com.mschematic.platform.services.ProductManager, com.mschematic.platform.services.Reference, com.mschematic.platform.services.Sales, com.mschematic.platform.services.Scripting, com.mschematic.platform.services.ServicingService, com.mschematic.platform.services.WaitList)
[DEBUG] Plugin Dependencies will be excluded.
[DEBUG] Project Dependencies will be included.
[DEBUG] Collected project artifacts [com.mschematic.base.services:cu-services-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.services.ifx:cu-ifx-bean-wsv:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.tools:cu-gen-ifx-interface:jar:1.0.0:compile, com.mschematic.base.commonentity:cu-common-entity:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, org.jboss.ejb3:jboss-ejb3-ext-api:jar:2.0.0:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.6.6:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.6.6:compile, org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:runtime, org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:runtime, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.5.1:compile, org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile, com.mschematic.svcfactory:cu-svcframework-EJB:jar:1.0.0:compile, com.mschematic.activation:cu-shared:jar:1.0.0:compile, com.mschematic.platformmodel.base:cu-platform-model-base:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, org.ow2.jonas.osgi:javaee-api:jar:5.0.5:compile, org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-ejb-3.0-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile, org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jpa-1.0-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile, org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-connector-1.5-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile, org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jta-1.1-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile, org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-deployment-1.2-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile, org.ow2.spec.ee:ow2-jsr77-1.1-spec:jar:1.0-M1:compile, org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile, wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile, org.apache.tomcat:servlet-api:jar:6.0.14:compile, org.mortbay.jetty:jsp-api-2.1:jar:6.1.5:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxr_1.0_spec:jar:1.1:compile, javax.security:jacc:jar:1.1:compile, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-jaxws-api:jar:1.3:compile, jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile, jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile, xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile, xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile, com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.5:compile, stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.5:compile, org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:jar:1.2.5:compile, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile, org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.1:compile, commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.2:compile, javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile, javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile, org.apache.axis2:axis2-saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile, javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.2_08:compile, javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_08:compile, org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile, org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.6.ga:compile, net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile, asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile, antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile, cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile, asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1.1:compile, org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile, javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile, org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.0.0.ga:compile, org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.1.GA:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile, javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile, com.mschematic.platform:cu-subsystems:jar:1.0.0:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.reference:cu-reference-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.authority:cu-authority-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.bpmcase:cu-bpmcase-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:jar:3.2.0.ga:compile, org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile, freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.8:compile, org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.forms:cu-forms-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.product:cu-product-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.sales:cu-sales-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.servicing:cu-servicing-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.tellercomponent.base:cu-teller-component-base:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.base.components.inbox:cu-inbox-ejb:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.extension.tellerdevices.print:cu-teller-print-agent:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.sun.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:compile, jp.co.epson:epsonupos:jar:1.4.2_16-b05:compile, com.sun.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile, jpos:jpos:jar:1.3.0_02:compile, jp.co.epson:pos:jar:1.4.2_16-b05:compile, jp.co.epson:uposcommon:jar:1.4.2_16-b05:compile, xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile, com.mschematic.extension.tellerdevices.print:cu-teller-print-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, jp.glory.cashier:ds-glory-cashier:jar:1.0.0:compile, gnu.io:rxtxcomm:jar:1.5.0:compile, com.mschematic.extension.tellerdevices.cashdevice:cu-teller-cashdevice-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, com.mschematic.extension.tellerdevices.cashdevice:cu-teller-cashdevice-server:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.7.RELEASE:compile, commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile, com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.6:compile, org.swinglabs:pdf-renderer:jar:1.0.5:compile, es.arcadiaconsulting.javapns:javapns:jar:2.2-json:compile, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile, bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:140:compile, com.mschematic.tools:cu-gen-ws-proxy:jar:1.0.0:compile]
[DEBUG] Collected project classpath [F:\khaja\cu-maven\channelUnited\parent\base\cu-services\cu-services-ifx-client\target\classes]
[DEBUG] Adding to classpath : file:/F:/khaja/cu-maven/channelUnited/parent/base/cu-services/cu-services-ifx-client/target/classes
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-services-common to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-ifx-bean-wsv to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-gen-ifx-interface to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-common-entity to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jboss-ejb3-ext-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cxf-rt-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cxf-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: woodstox-core-asl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: stax2-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jaxb-impl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: xmlschema-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-svcframework-EJB to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-shared to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-platform-model-base to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: javaee-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ow2-ejb-3.0-spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ow2-jpa-1.0-spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ow2-connector-1.5-spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ow2-jta-1.1-spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ow2-deployment-1.2-spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ow2-jsr77-1.1-spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axis-jaxrpc to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axis-saaj to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: wsdl4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: servlet-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jsp-api-2.1 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: geronimo-jaxr_1.0_spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jacc to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: mail to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: activation to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: geronimo-jms_1.1_spec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axis2-jaxws-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jaxen to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jdom to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: xom to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: xmlParserAPIs to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: icu4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axiom-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: stax-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axiom-impl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axiom-dom to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: xalan to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: wstx-asl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-io to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jaxb-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: stax-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: axis2-saaj-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jsf-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jsf-impl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: hibernate-entitymanager to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: hibernate to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ehcache to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: asm-attrs to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: dom4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: antlr to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cglib to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: asm to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-collections to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: hibernate-annotations to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: persistence-api to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: hibernate-commons-annotations to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ejb3-persistence to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-logging to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: javassist to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-subsystems to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-reference-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-lang to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-authority-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-bpmcase-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: hibernate-tools to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: bsh to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: freemarker to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jtidy to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-forms-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-product-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-sales-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-servicing-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-teller-component-base to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-inbox-ejb to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-teller-print-agent to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jai_codec to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: epsonupos to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jai_core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: jpos to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: pos to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: uposcommon to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: xercesImpl to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: xml-apis to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-teller-print-client to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: ds-glory-cashier to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: rxtxcomm to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-teller-cashdevice-client to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-teller-cashdevice-server to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: spring-beans to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: spring-core to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: commons-pool to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: itextpdf to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: pdf-renderer to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: javapns to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: log4j to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: bcprov-jdk16 to classpath
[DEBUG] Adding project dependency artifact: cu-gen-ws-proxy to classpath
[DEBUG] joining on thread Thread[com.mschematic.tools.proxygen.WsProxyGen.main(),5,com.mschematic.tools.proxygen.WsProxyGen]
[DEBUG] Setting accessibility to true in order to invoke main().
```

Answer (score 0):

looked at the source code using JadClipse eclipse plugin. The main method is calling System.exit(0) at the end of the method which is causing the maven process to be killed.

Hope this would help someone in the future.